# How to disable IR2110?

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver

I made a H bridge using 2 half drive like the picture
[image]
this works fine, but how can I disable the driver IR2110?

I'm afraid to put 0,0 in the input and that the driver will burn

Comment: Explain your reasoning that makes you think HIN = 0 and LIN = 0 will burn the driver. But before you answer, think about how the IR2110 is normally used.

Comment: Absolutely nothing wrong with pulling both inputs low to disable the driver.

Comment: The "SD" pin stands for "shutdown".

Comment: Sorry, I was afraid because I burned 10 drivers, it works perfect putting 0.0 in the input